# Accessing a file content using shell script

Tags: shell-script

I need to get user and password from a file and use that in my script

My file looks like below(netrc is my file name)

```
machine ftp.test.net login test_user password test_pass
machine ftp1.test.net login test_user1 password test_pass1
```

I want to write a function to access the file and fetch the username and password for particular machine

Comment: Sure! Show us what you've got, and tell us what happens when you run it. Click [edit] to add that to your original question. Please don't click Add Comment as new comments can push old comments off screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```bsh
login=$(grep $mymachin "$myfile" | cut -d' ' -f3)
password=$(grep $mymachin "$myfile" | cut -d' ' -f5)
```

or even better

```bsh
# reading the file only once
login_password=$(grep $mymachin "$myfile" | cut -d' ' -f3,5)
login=$(cut -d' ' -f1 <<<$login_password)
password=$(cut -d' ' -f2 <<<$login_password)
```

An alternative method now I have properly read the example, using the keywords instead of the position:

```bsh
line=$(grep $mymachin "$myfile")
login=$(sed 's/.*login \(.*\) .*/\1/' <<<$line)
password=$(sed 's/.*password \(.*\) .*/\1/' <<<$line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
get_netrc_user () {
    awk -v machine="$1" '$2 == machine { print $4 }' netrc
}

get_netrc_user () {
    awk -v machine="$1" '$2 == machine { print $6 }' netrc
}
```

The first function fetches the username/login given a particular machine, and the second one fetches the password.

To use:

```sh
username=$( get_netrc_user 'ftp.test.net' )
password=$( get_netrc_pass 'ftp.test.net' )
```

The `get_netrc_pass` assumes that the password never contains any whitespace though.  If it does, we can change it to be a bit more safe:

```sh
get_netrc_user () {
    awk -v machine="$1" '$2 == machine { sub(".*password ", "", $0); print }' netrc
}
```

Now, instead of returning the 6th whitespace-delimited field from the file, we delete everything up to the string `password` (with a space at the end) and return what remains of the line.  This would still fail if the password contains that string obviously.

Answer (score -1):

I would use cat to output the file, grep to select tha machine and awk to filter the fields (in your case the password and so).

So something like this

```
login=$(cat $myfile | grep $mymachine | awk '{print $4}')
```

Comment: UUOC and UUOG in one command.

Answer (score -1):

Done with below commands for fetching username and password

```
username=`awk '/Machinename/{print $4}' filename`
pass=`awk '/Machinename/{print $6}' filename`
```

Comment: You saw [Kusalananda's answer using the same method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526975/117549), right? Theirs even makes the input a variable, making it more flexible (as seen with the function parameter).